# Splitting a string via Regex and Maxsplit returns multiple splits

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of strings taken from chat log data, and I am trying to find the optimal method of splitting the speaker from the content of speech. Two examples are as follows:

```
mystr = ['bob123 (5:09:49 PM): hi how are you', 
         'jane_r16 (12/01/2020 1:39:12 A.M.) : What day is it today?']
```

Note that, while they are broadly similar, there are some stylistic differences I need to account for (inclusion  of dates, period marks, extra spaces etc.). I require a way to standardize and split such strings, and others like these, into something like the following list:

```
mystrList = [['bob123','hi how are you'],['jane_r16','What day is it today']]
```

Given that I do not need the times, numbers, or most punctuation, i thought a reasonable first step would be to remove anything non-essential. After doing so, I now have the following:

```
myCleanstr = ['bob(): hi how are you','janer() : What day is it today?']
```

Doing this has given me a pretty unique sequence of characters per string **():** that is unlikely to appear elsewhere in the same string. My subsequent thinking was to use this as a de-marker to split each string using Regex:

```
mystr_split = [re.split(r'\(\)( ){,2}:', i, maxsplit=1, flags=re.I) for i in myCleanstr]
```

Here, my intention was the following:

- `\(\)` Find a sequence of an open followed by a closed parentheses symbol
- `( ){,2}` Then find zero, one, or two whitespaces
- `:` Then find a colon symbol

However, in both instances, I receive three objects per string. I get the correct speaker ID, and speech content. But, in the first string I get an additional `NoneType Object`, and in the second string I get an additional string filled with a single white-space.

I had assumed that including `maxsplit=1` would mean that the process would end after the  first split has been found, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Rather than filter my results on the content I need I would like to understand why it is performing as it is.

Comment: Are the input strings always following the format 'SpeakerName followed by optional combination of spaces and date/time followed by zero or more spaces followed by speech content'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(\S+)\s*\([^()]*\)\s*:\s*(.+)
```

Or, if the name can have whitespaces:

```py
^(\S[^(]*?)\s*\([^()]*\)\s*:\s*(.+)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/WEwqhL/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/WEwqhL/2). The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: any one or more whitespace chars
- `[^(]*?` - zero or more chars other than a `(` char, as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the whole rest of the line).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WxzIOW):

```py
import re
result = []
mystr = ['bob123 (5:09:49 PM): hi how are you', 'jane_r16 (12/01/2020 1:39:12 A.M.) : What day is it today?']
for s in mystr:
    m = re.search(r'^(\S+)\s*\([^()]*\)\s*:\s*(.+)', s)
    if m:
        result.append([z for z in m.groups()])
print(result)
# => [['bob123', 'hi how are you'], ['jane_r16', 'What day is it today?']]
```